# Loop through json array and group items

Tags: jquery

I have an ajax call like this:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'assets/ajax/get-results.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: {}, 
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      
      for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var month = data[i]['month'];
          var year = data[i]['year'];
          var sum_bezoeken = data[i]['sum_bezoeken'];
          var sum_verkocht = data[i]['sum_verkocht'];
          var postal = data[i]['postal'];
          var type = data[i]['type'];

          var t = (parseInt(sum_bezoeken) / parseInt(sum_verkocht));
          console.log(t);
          
          $('.gem_'+month+'_'+year+'_'+postal).html(t);
     
      }         
    }
  });
```

`console.log(data)` gives me:

```
(14) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  0: {sum_verkocht: '1', postal: '1000', month: 'november', year: '2021', type: 'verkocht'}
  1: {sum_verkocht: '5', postal: '1000', month: 'oktober', year: '2021', type: 'verkocht'}
  2: {sum_verkocht: '0', postal: '2000', month: 'oktober', year: '2021', type: 'verkocht'}
  3: {sum_verkocht: '4', postal: '3000', month: 'oktober', year: '2021', type: 'verkocht'}
  4: {sum_verkocht: '6', postal: '6000', month: 'oktober', year: '2021', type: 'verkocht'}
  5: {sum_verkocht: '0', postal: '7000', month: 'oktober', year: '2021', type: 'verkocht'}
  6: {sum_bezoeken: '10', postal: '1000', month: 'november', year: '2021', type: 'bezoeken'}
  7: {sum_bezoeken: '10', postal: '2000', month: 'november', year: '2021', type: 'bezoeken'}
  8: {sum_bezoeken: '40', postal: '1000', month: 'oktober', year: '2021', type: 'bezoeken'}
  9: {sum_bezoeken: '10', postal: '2000', month: 'oktober', year: '2021', type: 'bezoeken'}
  10: {sum_bezoeken: '0', postal: '3000', month: 'oktober', year: '2021', type: 'bezoeken'}
  11: {sum_bezoeken: '0', postal: '6000', month: 'oktober', year: '2021', type: 'bezoeken'}
  12: {sum_bezoeken: '0', postal: '7000', month: 'oktober', year: '2021', type: 'bezoeken'}
  13: {sum_bezoeken: '0', postal: '8000', month: 'oktober', year: '2021', type: 'bezoeken'}
length: 14
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

`console.log(t)` gives me NaN.

See screenshot below: there is a row 'gemiddeld' and per postal code (columns), month and year I want to divide sum_bezoeken / sum_verkocht

This $('.gem_'+month+'*'+year+'*'+postal).html(t); goes to the HTML table row 'gemiddeld'.
See below example of HTML table row 'gemiddeld':

```
                        <tr>
                          <td style="width: 15%; font-weight: 500;">Gemiddeld</td>
                          <td class="text-center gem_<?php echo dutch_format($t['m']); ?>_<?php echo $t['y']; ?>_1000">0</td>
                          <td class="text-center gem_<?php echo dutch_format($t['m']); ?>_<?php echo $t['y']; ?>_2000">0</td>
                          <td class="text-center gem_<?php echo dutch_format($t['m']); ?>_<?php echo $t['y']; ?>_3000">0</td>
                          <td class="text-center gem_<?php echo dutch_format($t['m']); ?>_<?php echo $t['y']; ?>_6000">0</td>
                          <td class="text-center gem_<?php echo dutch_format($t['m']); ?>_<?php echo $t['y']; ?>_7000">0</td>
                          <td class="text-center gem_<?php echo dutch_format($t['m']); ?>_<?php echo $t['y']; ?>_8000">0</td>
                          <td class="text-center gem_<?php echo dutch_format($t['m']); ?>_<?php echo $t['y']; ?>_9000">0</td>
                          <td class="text-center">0</td>
                        </tr>
```

[HTML table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXIAh.png)

Comment: First, you need something like `var t = (parseInt(sum_bezoeken) / parseInt(sum_verkocht))`;

Comment: Second, what do you mean group by day, month, and year? Like have an array with all the values? Or a sum with all the values?

Comment: I have updated my post with parseInt. I added also an image with the view of HTML table. There is a row 'gemiddeld' and per postal code (columns), month and year i want to devide sum_bezoeken / sum_verkocht

Comment: Could you show me what it currently looks like?

Comment: Now the var t gives me 14 times  NaN in console if i do console.log(t);

Comment: Your objects do NOT contain both sum_verkocht AND sum_bezoeken
So the results of a division of sum_bezoeken / sum_verkocht will result a NaN value,
Since in first half of your data sum_bezoeken is undefined, and in the other half, sum_bezoeken is undefined.
To fix this, you would need to group the data by month/year/day and then attempt the calculation.

Comment: Please do not add solutions into the question. If the problem is not reproducible then you can delete the question. If you think others will run into the same issue then post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edit: Add `sum_bezoeken` to your PHP response.

To fix the division problem, you need to <strike>[`parseInt()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_parseint) because you are receiving the data as a string</strike> make sure `var sum_bezoeken = data[i]['sum_bezoeken']` is defined.

(If you look at the JSON data, the key is missing.)

To group the items, you need do something like:

1. Create something like `var group = {}`
2. When looping through the items, do something like: `group[month + '_' + year] = { /* Your data */ }`
3. Then you'll end up with a object like: `var group = { oktober_2021: [ ... ], november_2021: [ ... ], /* ... */}`

Comment: I can't follow you here... What you mean with 'Your data'?

Comment: @TPProjects By "your data", I meant the JSON data you posted. Investigating the problem a little more, I realized the real problem is that `var sum_bezoeken = data[i]['sum_bezoeken']` is undefined.

Comment: var sum_bezoeken = data[i]['sum_bezoeken']; is in the for loop and there is a correct result for that. In JSON array there are some rows with sum_bezoeken and sum_verkocht with the same month, year and postal

Comment: Maybe i have to change the PHP array before? Do you want me to post this code also?

Comment: @TPProjects: What is `var sum_bezoeken = data[i]['sum_bezoeken']` supposed to do? Think about it and how it's not doing what it suppose to be doing.

Comment: Yes you are right. The query in the PHP array was wrong. I changed it and now it works

Comment: @TPProjects Excellent! Could you accept my answer if that solves your problem?